# Exporting A4 size

Tags: export

I have a few tables and graphs that I want to export to a PDF file using Export[....,"PDF"], but I would like to be able to print this PDF-file and still be able to read it. 
So how can I control the width etc. of the file such that it fits on A4 pages, and how can I e.g. insert page breaks?

Answer (score 0):

You can get more Information from: [Page Layout & Printing Control](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/PageLayoutAndPrintingControl.html)

On Menu -> Printing Settings and ff you can interact with the Printing Environment. Distinguish carefully which Printing Environment you choose and select the appropriate page size.

[image]

With Menu -> Insert -> Page Break, you can set up these.

[image]

Comment: Actually don't want to print Mathematica code, but only the figures I exported to a PDF-file.

Comment: @user18798 you should update the question in this case, it is somewhat ambiguous.